# VMWare - Not able to share files between guest and host OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, vmware-player, shared-folders

I am using VMPlayer. My host OS is Windows 8 and my guest OS is Lubuntu. When I go to

```
Manage -> Virtual Machine Settings
```

and click on the 'Options' tab and click on 'Shared Folders' it says it is enabled and it says that it is linking to

```
C:\Users\userName\Documents\virtualMachineSharedDrive
```

but when I put a file in the

```
virtualMachineSharedDrive
```

folder, it does not appear in

```
/mnt/hgfs
```

and when I try to palce a file in

```
/mnt/hgfs
```

it says

```
fileName: Error creating directory: Permission denied
```

why is it denying permissions? And why can't I see files which are already in the folder placed by my host OS?

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 14.04. In 10.04 shared folders worked seamlessly with older versions of VMWare. But when I upgraded, VMware could "see" the shared folders (run vmware-hgfsclient) but they were not mountable at /mnt/hgfs/

I upgraded VMware to v6.0.4, reconfigured the VMWare tools (which rebuilds the modules against the latest kernel), and it worked flawlessly.

So, for Ubuntu 10.04 you need VMWare 6.0.4